# How to upgrade exiting sqlite db?

Tags: android, sqlite

i was published android apps using sqlite in local db.now i am add one more table in that db.how to upgrade existing db to user.i.e user data can't delete.only my update  will effect when user update previous apps version.how to handle this issue?how to republish my application?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override onUpgrade method of SQLiteOpenHelper

```
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
        db.execSQL(CREATE_NEW_TABLE);//create your new table
        //execute other sql statements if required
}
```

Did in one of my project here is [Link](https://github.com/gopalB/FeedReader/blob/master/src/com/feedReader/provider/FeedDB.java). Hope this help

Comment: @Selva, you won't call it - Android will. Just ensure you increment your database version code in your call to the SQLiteOpenHelper super class constructor and Android will take care of calling onUpgrade for you. This will only work if you are using SQLiteOpenHelper - if you are not, then you will have to manually handle detecting when an upgrade is necessary.

Comment: You not need to call...when you create object of SQLLiteOpenHelper...android will take care of the things...it will compare DATABASE_VERSION and will take necessary steps.

Comment: ok i unterstand.i insert code inside onUpgrade() as db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" ("+id+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , "+
       name+ " TEXT)");  . what can i insert inside onCreate().Is it correct?